# How can I limit the amount of decimal places for a calculated float value?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, integer-division

When I calculated 5/2 the result is 2.500000, so I was wondering how I can limit the result of the float value to 2.50 instead. I am not using cout setprecision() or the fixed statement because I need the actual result of the arithmetic value to have only 2 decimal places.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you're trying to write a function which will limit a `float` to 2 decimal places? Is it meant to be rounded some way, so 123.456 would be 123.45 or 123.46?

Comment: Floating point numbers are not decimal numbers, and they don’t have the concept of a defined number of decimal places. For the case of `5/2` both  `2.500000` and `2.50` represent the same float, only their textual representation is different.

Comment: Then is it possible for the textual representation to result to 2.50 instead of 2.500000?

Comment: In case of `std::cout` this is the `std::setprecision`. But as you say that this is not what you are looking for it is not clear what you actually have/want to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use certain decimal places, how about using `ceil()`, `floor()`, `round()`?

Comment: The thing is that I'm actually supposed to program those functions which is why I'm asking this question on stackoverflow

Comment: @Code4life Then you should have mentioned that in the first place and shown what you've tried so far and explained what your problems are. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56179424/edit) your question.

Comment: There was a recent question doing just that within the last month concerning floating point. I'll try and find the link.

Comment: I calculated 5/2 and the result was 2.50000.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, 2/5 gives 2 because writing it like this will do integer division. Only `2.0f/5.0f` will give you back a float.

Secondly, the only thing `std::setprecision` does is modify how many digits are displayed on the console when you do `std::cout`, it doesnt change the value of your variable or expression.

If you want to round your result to say one decimal place and not use standard functions, you could do something like

```
float a = 3.1415;
float b = ((int)(a*10+0.5))/10.0       // b is a rounded to one decimal place
```

but if you set `std::setprecision` to say 5 decimal places, it will still show you all the zeros after the last decimal place.